# How do i implement an indented border

Tags: html, css, border, indentation, centering

just wanted to know how i can change my navigation menu to have an indented effect. Like 1px of one light colour, and 1 px of darker colour.

Also does anybody know why i couldn't auto center the content in white, i tried margin:0 auto; but had to code in a weird workaround.

soz, site is http://digitalgenesis.com.au/sites/1
Cheers
Daz

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use [`border-style: inset;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-style) for the border effect you want, there's no need for nested block trickery or anything like that.

Your `#infowrap` element won't auto-center with a simple `margin: 0 auto;` because it is a block element and hence its default width is the width of its parent, this causes the `auto` left and right margins to come out as zero. The `margin: 0 auto;` will work if you wrap the insides in a block and give it an explicit width (for example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aMemg/).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jkmwy/

you can style the border left/right/top/bottom to create a bevel effect.

## html

```
<div id="a"><div id="b">blah</div></div>
```

## css

```
#b {
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
    line-height: 200px;
}

#a {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 300px;

}

body {
    background-color: black;
}
```